# Не могу запустить Maui приложение

Tags: c#, linux, .net, maui

При попытке запустить Maui приложение выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38, 5): [NETSDK1147] для сборки этого проекта необходимо установить следующие рабочие нагрузки: maui-android
Чтобы установить эти рабочие нагрузки, выполните следующую команду: dotnet workload restore
```

Пишу в консоль данную команду и мне выдает:

```
[taskavan@192 Maui-Clock]$ dotnet workload restore
Установка рабочих нагрузок: maui-android

Рабочие нагрузки "maui-android" уже установлены.
Пропуск проверки подписи пакета NuGet.
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.android версии 33.0.46...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.ios версии 16.2.2054...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst версии 16.2.2054...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.macos версии 13.1.2054...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.maui версии 7.0.81...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.sdk.tvos версии 16.1.2551...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net6 версии 7.0.5...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net7 версии 7.0.5...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.net6 версии 7.0.5...
Установка манифеста рабочей нагрузки microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.net7 версии 7.0.5...
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Sdk версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Sdk" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.net7 версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Sdk версии 6.0.547…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Sdk" версии 6.0.547 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.net6 версии 6.0.547…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Graphics версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Graphics" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Graphics версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net7 версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net7" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net7 версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net6 версии 6.0.547…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net6" версии 6.0.547 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net6 версии 6.0.547…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net7 версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux версии 32.0.476…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux" версии 32.0.476 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net6 версии 32.0.476…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Ref.33 версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Ref.33" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Ref.33 версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm64 версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm64" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-arm64 версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x86 версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x86" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x86 версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x64 версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x64" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Runtime.33.android-x64 версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Android.Templates версии 33.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.Android.Templates" версии 33.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Android.Templates версии 33.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-arm версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-arm64 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-x64 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-x86 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net6 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.net6 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x86 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x86" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-x86 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x64 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x64" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-x64 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-arm версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm64 версии 6.0.15…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm64" версии 6.0.15 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-arm64 версии 6.0.15…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net7.android-arm версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net7.android-arm64 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net7.android-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net7.android-x86 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x86 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x86" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net7.android-x86 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-x64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net7.android-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net7.android-arm версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.android-arm64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net7.android-arm64 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Пакет "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.tizen" версии 7.0.49 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.tizen версии 7.0.49…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net7.browser-wasm версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.browser-wasm версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.linux-x64.Cross.browser-wasm" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net7.browser-wasm версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Node.linux-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Node.linux-x64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.Node.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Cache.linux-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Cache.linux-x64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.Cache.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет установка пакета Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Sdk.linux-x64 версии 7.0.4…
Пакет "Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Sdk.linux-x64" версии 7.0.4 уже установлен.
Идет запись установки пакета рабочей нагрузки для Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.Sdk.net7 версии 7.0.4…
Идет сбор мусора для диапазонов компонентов SDK 7.0.100…

Рабочие нагрузки maui-android android maui-tizen wasm-tools установлены.
```

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так я не могу запустить код, хоть он и пишет, что все установлено.

Comment: зпустить код под линуксом? а MAUI это поддерживает вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 на стационаре стоит Arch и под ним все нормально запускается, а на ноутбуке с федорой траблы какие-то, хотя делал все тоже самое

Comment: Среди [поддерживаемых платформ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-7.0) нет ни того, ни другого. То есть оно и не обязано вообще запускаться на федоре.

Comment: @tym32167 ну раз на арче он запустился значит есть способ запустить и на федоре, как я считаю

Comment: этого я не знаю ¯\_(ツ)_/¯